# Sumif loop through data groups vba

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, sumifs, vba

If this is answered elsewhere please advise...

I am trying to come up with a sumif that will sum column D if Column A criteria = "PL211010" & "PL203000". The problem is that I need the macro to sum by groups rather than the whole sheet (see pic)[image]

Not sure where to even start, should i be using a For Next loop? or is a loop even necessary?

*Important note* This pivot dynamically changes month to month. The accounts are not static, they can either increase or decrease. So placing a static formula will not work...

The code below is my attempt to get this to work, just trying to give a baseline.

```
Dim nRowMax, nRowNow As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Cells(4, 1).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
nRowMax = Selection.Row

For i = nRowMax To 4 Step -1
If Left(Cells(i, 1), 8) = "PL211010" & "PL203000" Then
        WorksheetFunction.SumIf (Cells(i, 4))
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: No it changes dynamically which is why I have the nRowMax function in there. The photo is a small sample of a pivot that could go hundreds of rows down. Currently being done by hand takes awhile

Comment: This would probably be much easier if you look at the pivot's data source rather than basically making a "pivot of a pivot".

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without VBA by writing formulas directly on the datasource as @ashleedawg stated, and that would probably be your easiest option, or by writing them directly off the pivot. I have done a mock-up example below that will work for the case you provided:

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

1. Change the Pivot Table Layout as I have instructed in the picture in cell D1
2. Use the formula in cell H4: `=SUM(SUMIFS($F$4:$F$11,$D$4:$D$11,D4,$E$4:$E$11,{"A","B"}))`
3. Drag down as needed.

Now, it's late for me and I did this quick, so I realize it's repetitive and a bit messy. For that you can simply organize a list of single elements and write the formulas off that list.

Alternatively, you can write the formulas directly off the data source by modifying the range arguments of the formula I provided.

Comment: Yeah maybe I need to mention in my question that the pivot dynamically changes so one month the BEVGR might be 5 rows and another month be 15 rows. So having a static formula will not work

Comment: @GabeCarvajal - that's a simple fix: instead of using `$F$4:$F$11`, just use `$F:$F`

Comment: If I do that than its going to do a subtotal of the entire pivot table... I am trying to sum each group not the whole pivot table. If i were to collapse the whole pivot table there would be 26 groups so i need 26 different totals. Your solution would just get me one total.

Comment: @GabeCarvajal - no. it will only sum the group you are after since you are also checking against column D in the SUMIF (which captures the group)